# Windows Explorer "Command Prompt Here"

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

I frequently find myself with a folder open in Windows, wishing to have a command prompt open with the same working directory.

I am aware of Power Toys "Command Prompt", but that only works as a context menu item on the folder, and not from inside the folder if you are already there.  I know you can navigate to the parent directory, and use it from there, but if the parent has thousands of directories in it, this is not so convenient.  I have tried some home-brewed batch files associated with folder actions in explorer, but those suffer from similar problems.

So, what is the quickest way to open a command prompt with a working directory of the current windows explorer folder?

My current approach: (horrible)

- **<kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd>** (copy path)
- **<kbd>Win</kbd> - <kbd>R</kbd>, "cmd", <kbd>Enter</kbd>** (start command prompt)
- **"cd", <kbd>Space</kbd>** (start a change directory command)
- **<kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>p</kbd>** (paste directory)
- **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** (execute change directory)

I know there is something better!  What is it?

Comment: It's not specifically about a programming language, but the only reason I ever need to do this is because of something programming related, and I am sure others have encountered it as well.

Comment: @Daok I think you are too strict.Just look for questions tagged with 'command-line':'What is the safest way to empty a directory in *nix?','How can I diff two files with full context?',etc. Many programmers use cmd line which affects their productivity. I think it's valid question not related to IT.

Comment: Well for what it is worth, I feel that it really is an OS question. It is true that the OS definitely does effect programming, but everything in the programmer's life does and you have to draw the line somewhere.

Comment: @Daok: Get off your high horse!  Programmers often need tips about how to do their jobs faster; quickly getting to a command line is one of them.  You need you moderator privileges revoked, IMHO.

Comment: @recursive: Google for this; I found a small registry change for Windows XP that worked for any file in the folder, I think... but it was a long time ago, and I wanted to click the folder so I didn't pursue it.

Answer (score 440):

Hold **Shift** while **Right-Clicking** a blank space in the desired folder to bring up a more verbose context menu. One of the options is `Open Command Window Here`. This works in Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 10. Since Windows 10 Creators Update, the option has been replaced with `Open PowerShell Here`. However, there are ways to [enable `Open Command Window Here` again](https://superuser.com/q/1201988/269404).

Comment: This works from vista above. You can also shift+click on some folder itself

Comment: It also works in Windows XP, the difference is that you must click on the folder icon itself.

Comment: Full keyboard solution (Windows 7): `SHIFT+F10` to open the context menu, then press the letter associated to the command prompt ("f" in french). Cocorico :-)

Comment: @procrastinator F10 is to open the main menu. The context menu is opened by the menu key (the key between right Alt and right Ctrl), so you can use `Shift+Menu`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I don't have the "menu" key on my laptop :-|

Comment: Btw, dr. evil's answer still works with latest Windows 10. Just type `cmd` in location bar.

Comment: Those loking to get it back thnx to Win10CU,take ownership of and rename `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd,HideBasedOnVelocityId` key (add an underscore prefix or something) and command prompt option returns! ([ref](https://www.howtogeek.com/302408/how-to-put-open-command-window-here-back-on-the-windows-right-click-menu/))

Answer (score 329):

Just **type "cmd" to location bar**, that's it. It will start a new command prompt in current path.

This solution was confirmed to work in Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8 and 10 (including Creators Update).

Keystrokes to move the focus to the location bar:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in English (pointed out by Tim Stewart in the comments)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> in German

Comment: This trick also works with PowerShell for Windows 7/8/Server 2008+. Typing `powershell` in the command bar will bring up a powershell window set to that directory.

Comment: I love this mouseless approach. The only thing is that is will not work from a UNC location (\\server\sharename). Then you'll need to use shift right-click, Open command window here. A network drive will be created on the fly.

Comment: And if you're too lazy to even do this, you can use this autohotkey script to map it to CTRL+T: 
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
^T::
    Send !dcmd{Return}
    return
#endif

Comment: `Alt+D/E` doesn't work on a french laptop with Windows 7 :-(

Comment: how about **cmd as Administrator**?

Comment: this is just as good as the right-click method, which weirdly brings up only the PowerShell option for me (Win10 Pro).

Comment: @antikd - the r-click method ceased to offer the command prompt with the Creators Update (April/May 2017) to Win10, leaving just the Powershell option... why?

Comment: @Dave45 Microsoft wants to promote PowerShell.

Comment: Yes on Win 7; but no, absolutely not on XP as just tested. It opens a browser and goes to http://cmd/ then https://cmd.com/ . And no, I did not go control enter; just enter. And BTW you forgot to say to hit ENTER :) (or click to process it, generally a right-arrow icon)

Comment: Hey @leaf, can you try Ctrl + L? It is an alternative to move the focus to the location bar.

Comment: @DarkMatter It works thanks :-) But I upgraded to Windows 10 long ago :-|

Answer (score 30):

Inside your current folder, simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> --*then*--> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The prompt will appear with your current folder's path set.

Note: That works only in Windows 7 / Vista. What it does is that drops the "File" menu down for you, because the "Shift" key is pressed the option "Open command window here" is enabled and focused as the first available option of "File" menu. Pressing enter starts the focused option therefor the command window.

**Edit:**

In case you are in a folder and you already selected some of its contents (file/folder) this wont work. In that case Click on the empty area inside the folder to deselect any previously selected files and repeat.

**Edit2:**

Another way you can open terminal in current directory is to type `cmd` on file browser navigation bar where the path of current folder is written.

In order to focus with your keyboard on the navigation bar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. Then you can type `cmd` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: In Windows Explorer on Windows 7, that merely drops the file drop down menu for me.

Comment: Works for me (Windows 7 Professional)

Comment: The real gem here is that holding shift while accessing the File menu shows this command. Easier to remember than the key combo and I'm betting it works on Windows 10 too.

Answer (score 29):

[Right-click the title-bar icon of the Explorer window.](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/08/55223.aspx) You'll get the current folder's context menu, where you'll find the "command window here" item.

(Note that to see that menu item, you need to have [the corresponding "power toy"](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) installed, or you can [create the right registry keys](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/08/55223.aspx#55235) yourself to add that item to folders' context menus.)

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to do that with the keyboard?

Comment: Hugh, please see fm's answer: type "cmd" into the address bar. Based on the question's text, I gather you can get to the address bar with the keyboard with Alt+D.

Answer (score 28):

As a very quick solution I can give you this. I tested this on Windows 8.1

1- Find File and Right Click on Command Prompt on File Explorer and then add command prompt to your Quick Access Toolbar:

[image: Instruction 1]

2- After adding it you can access the folder from here:

[image: Instruction 2]

That will open a command prompt in there for you.

Comment: well thought out! People using W7 see my answer below.

Comment: This also works on Windows 10.

Comment: This is useful for most cases but I sometimes just drag folders and files to the desktop when working with a small amount of stuff. It just means that I don't need to make a new directory to put things from multiple directories into one place. Would be awesome if there was a solution for the desktop.

Comment: This was removed in the Windows 10 Creators Update. Powershell still remains though.

Answer (score 22):

On vista and windows 7:

- **Alt+d** -> it will put focus on the address bar of the explorer window
- and then, type the name of any program you would launch using WIN+r
- hit **Enter**

The program will start with its current directory set to that of the explorer instance.
e.g.:python, ghci, powershell, cmd, etc...

Answer (score 12):

You can edit the registry to add the Command Prompt item to the context menu. Here are a couple of .reg files that I use.

Cmdhere.reg - for WinNT/2000/XP/Vista/7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenNew]
@="Command Prompt"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenNew\Command]
@="cmd.exe /k cd %1"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\OpenNew]
@="Command Prompt"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\OpenNew\Command]
@="cmd.exe /k cd %1"
```

Doshere.reg - for Win9x:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenNew]
@="MS-DOS Prompt"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\OpenNew\Command]
@="command.com /k cd %1"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\OpenNew]
@="MS-DOS Prompt"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\OpenNew\Command]
@="command.com /k cd %1"
```

Copy this into an empty text file and change the extension to .reg. Double-clicking on this in Windows Explorer will add these key to the registry.

Comment: Used this and works perfectly :). But, how can I have a similar option with elevated privileges (will prompt for UAC naturally)?

Comment: All I needed to do was add a reg for `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell`, rather than `Directory` and `Drive`

Comment: It doesn't work on my Win 10, %1 param should be embraced with quotes like this: 
 
    ``command.com /k cd "%1" ``

And for Drive it doesn't work because cd  command could not change current drive.

Comment: In Windows 10 use File -> Open Windows PowerShell.
For help on command use (for example): Get-Help mkdir

Comment: `cmd /k cd "%v\."` worked for me in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd here\command`

Answer (score 12):

For Windows vista and Windows 7 ,to open the command prompt 
1) go to folder you want to work

2)In address bar type- cmd

press enter

it will open the command prompt for that location

Comment: this answer was given already five years before you. Why do people post identical answers over and over?

Comment: @Shirish thanks for the tip. your answer helped to save lot of time. worked in win10.

Answer (score 10):

I use StExBar, a Windows Explorer extension that gives you a command prompt button in explorer along with some other cool features (copy path, copy file name & more).

https://tools.stefankueng.com/StExBar.html

EDIT:
I just found out (been using it for more than a year and did not know this) that Ctrl+M will do it with StExBar.  How's that for fast!

Answer (score 4):

Almost the same as yours:

- **Alt+d**, **Ctrl+c**
- **Win+r**
- **cmd /K cd** , **Ctrl+v**, **ENTER**

Comment: Excellent!
The last line seems like it should be "cmd /K cd /D", Ctrl+v, ENTER

For posterity.

Comment: You may need "s if there are spaces in the path.

Answer (score 3):

If that's so bothering, you could try to switch to windows explorer alternative like [freecommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) which has a toolbar button for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I use a lot the "Send To" functionality.
I create my own batch (.bat) files in the `shell:sendto` folder and send files/folders to them using the context menu (to get there just write 'shell:sendto'  in location bar).
I have scripts to perform all sort of things: send files by ftp, launch a php server in the current folder, create folders named with the current date, copy sent path to clipboard, etc.
Sorry, a bit offtopic but useful anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Tried the [answer given by Tough Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23711877/382515) in Windows 7 and it works!

Create a shortcut to cmd.exe in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Links`, open its file properties and change the field 'Start at' to `%1` ('Iniciar en' translated from spanish).

Now drag folders to it and you'll see the magic. It works too in all standard Open File dialogs. wow!

ps: those 'strange' tabs above in my picture are because I use [Clover](http://ejie.me/). I recommend it!

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Use the following in command prompt to open your current location in windows explorer:

C:\your-directory> explorer .

Comment: off topic, the Q is about the other direction, opening CMD from Explorer.